# x264_encoder_open always return null

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, x264

this is  my code

x264_param_default(&m_X264Param) ;

```
nRet = x264_param_default_preset(&m_X264Param,"medium","zerolatency") ;
if (nRet)
{
    return -1;
}
if (cpMain == Param.nProfile)
{
    nRet = x264_param_apply_profile(&m_X264Param,"main") ;
}
else if (cpSimple == Param.nProfile)
{
    nRet = x264_param_apply_profile(&m_X264Param,"baseline") ;
}
else if (cpComplex == Param.nProfile)
{
    nRet = x264_param_apply_profile(&m_X264Param,"high");
}
if (nRet)
{
    return -1;
}
m_X264Param.i_width = Param.nWidth ;
m_X264Param.i_height = Param.nHeight ;
m_X264Param.i_threads = X264_THREADS_AUTO ;
m_X264Param.i_log_level = X264_LOG_NONE ;
m_X264Param.rc.i_bitrate = Param.nBitRate ;
m_X264Param.rc.i_rc_method = X264_RC_ABR ;
m_X264Param.i_csp          =  X264_CSP_I420 ;
```

m_pX264Handle = x264_encoder_open(&m_X264Param) ;

but it always return null it is my first time use it  did i miss some key param? is anyone who can tell me the answer! thank you very much and best regards

Answer (score 1):

Returned `NULL` is nothing but an indication of error, on parameter argument or in the environment.

Just an example how it might be happening:

```
x264_t *x264_encoder_open( x264_param_t *param )
{
    // ...
    if( x264_threading_init() )
    {
        x264_log( h, X264_LOG_ERROR, "unable to initialize threading\n" );
        goto fail;
    }
    // ...
fail:
    x264_free( h );
    return NULL;
}
```

Add a logging callback via `m_X264Param.pf_log` and friends and have it called with diagnostic messages supposedly explaining issues.

Answer (score 0):

No, I think encoder open should not return null. please check if the function name is correct, I think the build number is usually included in this function
like `x264_encoder_encode_130` etc.
also if you are using the dll then you got to link it properly -
I don't know much but just mah 2 cents yaw.